# How to set div height same as parent container without using percentage?

Tags: html, css

I am using an angular plugin called `angular-split`, it offers a gutter to split resize-able part on html page.

The problem is that if you want to split something, the div contains the gutter must be set a height in specific value, not percentage.

So my question is if I want my div to full fill the parent container without using `height=100%`, what could I do?

Answer (score 1):

Are those `divs` individually style along-with a `child` div, if so you can do that by changing the `display` of parent and child element. No need to assign `height` to child element it by default takes as `100%` of parent element.

Check below codes, red div is parent div and blue one child.

```css
#parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
  display: table;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;/*Optional*/
}

#parent .child {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work. I assume it requires a height value when initiating the gutter, not sure.

Comment: @Zanecat You need height to style gutter of same height, if so there must be something with plug-in that you are using, using jQuery you can get height of child element and assign that to gutter.